# aspnet c# webservice session, httpcontext and hack

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I got a webmethod like:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string some(string value)
{
 Vote vote = new Vote();
 vote.User.Id = ((User)Session["user"]).Id;
 vote.User.Address = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 vote.value = "";
 // store in the database, using GETDATE() to store the time.
 return "ok";
}
```

Its working ok, I can get the user id in the session, and the user ip in the httpcontext.

Today, I found 500 rows like:

```
USER      IP        DATE
1456      0.0.0.0   2011-09-28 02:54:38.493
1456      0.0.0.0   2011-09-28 02:54:38.493
1456      0.0.0.0   2011-09-28 02:54:38.493
1456      0.0.0.0   2011-09-28 02:54:38.493
```

To me it means that someone is using a bot to access the webmethod and make random votes, but I cant understand why the IP is coming '0.0.0.0', how the guy bypass the session problem, and how the guy can get the same exact time in all 500 rows. Any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address why the date is the same, DateTime is not very precise.  If all 500 came in at once (500 requests) then it could very well mark them all as having the same time within the granularity of the DATETIME precision.

As for the session, they just need to send back the encrypted cookie.  That means they login, get the cookie, then send requests using that cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this site](http://thepcspy.com/read/getting_the_real_ip_of_your_users/), it gives you some good information on why `REMOTE_ADDR` won't always work. The suggestion is to first check `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")` and if that fails, then check REMOTE_ADDR.